# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root"?

Tags: android

My FileProvider:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/files"/>

</provider>
```

files.xml:

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
</paths>
```

Trying to get uri:

```
File testFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "my_images");
File testFile2 = new File(testFile, "cool.jpg");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),
    "com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.fileprovider",
    testFile2);
```

The last method crashes the app:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent/files/my_images/cool.jpg
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:800)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:442)
        at com.bignerdranch.android.criminalintent.CrimeFragment.onViewCreated(CrimeFragment.java:214)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:2987)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:546)
...
```

I did it according to the official [site](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) but for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: `path="images/"` and `new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "my_images")` do not line up. I think perhaps you inverted the roles of `name` and  `path` in your `<files-path>` element.

Comment: @CommonsWare i've tried to pass the path instead of the name to second parameter. There is no exception. But after a camera app trying to load a photo to this uri in `files` directory there is no `images` directory and there is no photo accordingly. And yeah, [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) says that i have to pass exactly the NAME instead of the path to second parameter.

Comment: "But after a camera app trying to load a photo to this uri in files directory there is no images directory and there is no photo accordingly" -- well, you need to create the directory yourself. "the official documentation says that i have to pass exactly the name instead of the path to second parameter." -- those samples are incorrect. The `File` object that you create needs to be in a location that matches some combination of XML element and its `path` attribute.